# Clustering in herempa throws ERROR Error: Coordinates out of bounds at Pt.uc (mapsjs.bundle.js:684:95)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, markerclusterer, heremaps

I am using Here Map -javascript to cluster the datapoints

```
  
 function addToMapMarker(Poi, POIs) {
    console.log(Poi);
    const cord = { lat: Poi.location.latitude, lng: Poi.location.longitude };
    const parisMarker = new H.map.Marker(cord);
    this.hereMap.addObject(parisMarker);
    this.startClustering(this.hereMap, POIs, cord);
 }

  startClustering(map, Poi, cord) {
    const dataPoints = Poi.map(function(item) {
      return new H.clustering.DataPoint(item.latitude, item.longitude);
    });
    this.hereMap.setCenter(cord);
    const clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {
      clusteringOptions: {
        eps: 30,
        minWeight: 2
      }
    });
    const clusteringLayer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteredDataProvider);
    map.getLayers().add(clusteringLayer);
    map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({
      bounds: clusteredDataProvider.getRootGroup().getBoundingBox()
    });
    map.addLayer(clusteringLayer);
       // clusteredDataProvider.addEventListener('update', function(evt) {
    // // target is Provider itself after clustering is completed
    //   if (evt.target === this) {

    //   }
    // });

    // map.addLayer(clusteringLayer);
  }
```

I am new to the here map .Basically Map rendering ,COuld anyone please help to solve this issue.I went through docs and api ,not sure where I am going wrong